# Duplicate Contact Problem

Tags: contacts, joomla, duplicate-contacts

The new individual record is created, written phone number.
When registration opened again with a new phone number can be the same individual.
Telephone number of systems with the same record, I want to prevent the creation of new personal record.
I do not want this to happen Duplicate Contacts
How can I make this setting.

Joomla! 3.6.4
CiviCRM Ver: 4.7.12

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the deduplication rule to match what you need. Not sure I completely understood your use case, but it seems that you have included the phone number on your default unsupervised dedupe rule?

Check this chapter in the book if the dedupe rules are not clear for you yet, it's powerful, but takes a while to use them properly and a common source of duplicates being created.

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/common-workflows/deduping-and-merging/